# Eclipse 4 RCP - Application does not have an active window

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4

I am trying to setup my view with `EPartService`, but still getting exception on that line with `findPart` call. Am i doing it right way?

**Exception:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application does not have an active window
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ApplicationPartServiceImpl.getActiveWindowService(ApplicationPartServiceImpl.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ApplicationPartServiceImpl.findPart(ApplicationPartServiceImpl.java:87)
```

**Code:**

```java
package cz.vutbr.fit.xhriba01.bc.handler;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations.Execute;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.IServiceConstants;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.modeling.EPartService;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer;
import org.eclipse.jface.window.Window;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

import cz.vutbr.fit.xhriba01.bc.ui.ExplorerView;
import cz.vutbr.fit.xhriba01.bc.ui.dialogs.NewFromDirectoryDialog;

public class NewFromDirectoryHandler {

    @Inject 
    private EPartService fPartService;

    @Execute
    public void execute(@Named(IServiceConstants.ACTIVE_SHELL) Shell shell) {

        NewFromDirectoryDialog dialog = new NewFromDirectoryDialog(shell);
        dialog.create();
        if (dialog.open() == Window.OK) {
            String sourceDir = dialog.getSourceDir();
            String classDir = dialog.getClassDir();
            TreeViewer tv = ((ExplorerView)fPartService.findPart("bc.part.explorer").getObject()).getTreeViewer();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I also had the same problem, and this worked!! [https://stackoverflow.com/a/38230627/5799676](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38230627/5799676)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try injecting the `EPartService` as an argument to the `execute` method:

```java
@Execute
public void execute(EPartService fPartService, @Named(IServiceConstants.ACTIVE_SHELL) Shell shell)
```

It is best to avoid injecting fields in a handler as they will only be injected once when the handler is created. Things like `EPartService` change as the active part changes.

Comment: Can i ask if it is good idea how i am communicating with my UI? Because i now read that model classes could be disposed (but i don't know when), so if MPart is disposed, is disposed even that class it is showing (ExplorerView in my case)? Because in that case the information from dialog will be lost, because it exists only in that ExplorerView.

Comment: I would usually just use `@Named(IServiceConstants.ACTIVE_PART) MPart activePart` to inject the active part, and make sure the handler is only active for the correct part.

Comment: i though where to store my informations to be sure they will be not disposed later (eg. can be class representing view for MPart disposed by eclipse, or eclipse will dispose just that MPart and later when that MPart should be rendered, it will use the existing view)? Currently i just setup that TreeViewer. But if that TreeViewer will be disposed and rendered again, it will have no input.

Comment: You should use some non-UI object that you can inject wherever you need it. You could create an OSGi service to hold the data, or just an object that you inject in to the application context.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need write something like this:

```
public class NewFromDirectoryHandler {

    @Inject 
    private EPartService fPartService;

    @Inject 
    MApplication application

    @Execute
    public void execute(@Named(IServiceConstants.ACTIVE_SHELL) Shell shell) {

        NewFromDirectoryDialog dialog = new NewFromDirectoryDialog(shell);
        dialog.create();
        IEclipseContext activeWindowContext = application.getContext().getActiveChild();
        if (dialog.open() == Window.OK) {
            activeWindowContext.activate();
            String sourceDir = dialog.getSourceDir();
            String classDir = dialog.getClassDir();
            TreeViewer tv = ((ExplorerView)fPartService.findPart("bc.part.explorer").getObject()).getTreeViewer();
        }
    }
```

Save context before and restore after `dialog.open()`.

Answer (score 1):

As said by greg-449, it is better to inject EPartService in execute method.

If design situation forces you not to use EPartService in execute method, then below approach can be used.

```
IEclipseContext context = application.getContext();
MTrimmedWindow window = (MTrimmedWindow) application.getChildren().get(0);
IEclipseContext windowContext = window.getContext();
context.activate();
windowContext.setParent(context);
windowContext.activateBrach();
EPartService partService = windowContext.get(EPartService.class);
```

Then this partService can be used to findPart or createPart.

Problem what I think is, the application context doesnt have active child. Code inside EPartService sees the active leaf different from active child.

Active leaf can also be obtained by:

```
IEclipseContext activeLeaf = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(IEclipseContext.class).getActiveLeaf();
```

If the leaf is already active, then that can also be used to get EPartService